# Evaluation of Summations

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

In my textbook, we are given the sum: $ S =\sum_{i=10}^{50} i$.

The solution states that we can write the sum as $ S =\sum_{i=10}^{50} i = (\sum_{i=1}^{50} i) - (\sum_{i=1}^{9} i) $.

My question is how did we get from  $\sum_{i=10}^{50} i$ to $ (\sum_{i=1}^{50} i) - (\sum_{i=1}^{9} i) $?

Thanks in advance! Sorry if my formatting is crappy. I'm relatively new to this MathJax thing.

Comment: Note: $\sum_{i=10}^{50} i=10+11+\cdots +50 =(1+2+\cdots +50)-(1+2+\cdots +9)=(\sum_{i=1}^{50} i) - (\sum_{i=1}^{9} i)$

Comment: Next time, try coming up with a more specific title for your questions, as it will attract more solvers :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that simply we are subtracting $1+...+9$ from $1+...+50$ to obtain $10+...+50$.